# Guzzle POST request results in 500 error even though Curl for that works

Tags: php, json, curl, post, guzzle

I have the below chunk of PHP code for hitting a POST API

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['debug'=>true]);
$response = $client->request(
    $request_method,
    $request_url,
    [
        'json' => $request_data,
        'http_errors' => false
    ]
);

$http_code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

This results in a 500 response from the server, despite all Headers being properly listed in the debug logs as below:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.xxx.xx.xx...
* Connected to <<hostname>> (52.xxx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/rest/auth_key HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.38.0 PHP/7.0.9-1~dotdeb+8.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: <<hostname>>
Content-Length: 42

* upload completely sent off: 42 out of 42 bytes
```

**$request_url** above is the complete url for the POST request.
**$request_data** is JSON content (PHP associative array) to be sent.
**$request_method** is **'POST'**.

Even if I remove the json data from the request, expecting to get a 400 response from the API, I still get the same 500 error.
The same request when triggered via Curl works fine with the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $request_url,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $request_method,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($request_data),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "content-type: application/json"
  ],
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Have been trying to debug this for quite some time & even looked for similar references in SO but to no avail. Any helps in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment, since I don't have enough reputation, so if this does not answer your question or resolve the issue, sorry in advance.

I had been experiencing a similar issue, where cURL was working no problem, but I was getting either a 500 response or a 400 Bad Request (Request Too Long). It turns out that when you include json data in the third parameter for a POST request, it is being included in the request's header.

The documentation has some examples where the fourth parameter of the `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` class is used as the body of the request (see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html). Once I used this and set the content type explicitly in the header, my issues were resolved.

That means that your request would look like this:

```
$response = $client->request(
    $request_method,
    $request_url,
    ['Content-Type'=>'application/json'],
    json_encode($request_data)
);
```

Hopefully this will help you out too!